# While running two thread in while loop with sleep time 1000 ms, getting an error " unable to create new native thread"

Tags: java

I created two threads. Inside `run()` method, running threads under while loop with sleep time of 1000ms. When I'm running this program, after sometime, I'm getting the error:

> unable to create new native thread

My code:(updated)

```
class MainClass{
RunThread t1 = new RunThread("read_thread");
t1.start();
RunThread t2 = new RunThread("write_thread");
t2.start();
System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
}

class RunThread implements Runnable{
Thread t;
String threadName;

public RunThread(String name){
threadName=name;
}

public void start(){
if(t==null)
t = new Thread(this,threadName);
t.start();
}

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
           if(threadName.equalsIgnoreCase("read_thread")){     
               //do something    
System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
                  Thread.sleep(1000);  
               }    
            if (threadName.equalsIgnoreCase("write_thread")) {    
                   //do something 
System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                  }
              }
```

Comment: how do you create the threads please share the code

Comment: Consider adding the stacktrace as well

Comment: MainClass{ RunnableThread t1 = new Runnable("read_thread");    RunnableThread t2 = new Runnable("write_thread");}

Comment: Please update your question instead of writing into comments.

Comment: MainClass {   RThread t1 = new RThread ("read"); t1.start();    RThread t2 = new RThread ("write"); t2.start();     }   RThread implements Runnable{                                                                        Thread t;  String threadName;     public   RThread (String name){threadName=name; }                        
 public void start()  {                                                  t=new Thread(this,threadName);                                                                                t.start();    }

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: It looks as if you're starting a new thread in your Thread.start() method. You're creating 100000s of threads that way.

Comment: I have updated the code. When i am printing Thread.activeCount()- it is coming 4. But only 3 thread are running [main thread, read thread, write thread].

Comment: Your code has many compilation errors. To get help, you should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I tried making your code compilable and after doing so, I **could not reproduce** the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your start() method, which creates a new Thread object, calls itself recursively (and indefinitely).

Creating a Thread object effectively creates a new thread at the OS level as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.ThreadGroup,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String)).

Thus either:

a) the system cannot allocate more memory to instantiate those threads or

b) you reached a limit to the number of threads your OS can handle.

Comment: I modified the code and took care of this mentioned above. I am creating and starting thread from start1() method. Still Thread.activeCount() is increasing. Output is coming like this..                                                                          Thread Count =4                                                                                        
Thread Count =4                                                                                        
 Thread Count =5

Comment: I can't understand you, sorry. Also I don't see any "Thread.activeCount()" in your code.

Comment: Ok. That doesn't change your question tough. Which I think I answered already.

Comment: I think we are barking up the wrong tree. The OP's `start()` method actually calls `t.start()` which is *not* a recursive call. The methods `RunThread.start()` and `Thread.start()` are completely different and unrelated, even if they do happen to have the same name.

Comment: That's correct and Thread.start() is getting called only once. But when i added Thread.activeCount() in run() method. I found that with some interval of time, this count is increasing and RAM space is also getting occupied and throwing "OutOfMemory exception- unable to create new native thread". I am running only two thread in while loop then why this count is increasing.

Comment: @Anuj.Nogja the code you show in your question only creates 2 threads. There must be something else that you haven't shown us (denoted by the "//do something" comments) that creates other threads.